# Show only Domain name with pretty faces

Tags: jsf-2, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

I have a JSF2 app and I would like to show only the domain name in the Browser for every page. Example:

http://www.example.com/index.jsf
to
http://www.example.com

Therefore I configured PrettyFaces like this:

```
<url-mapping id="index">
    <pattern value="/" />
    <view-id value="/index.jsf"/>
</url-mapping>
```

But then, I get the 404 error message "The requested resource (/index.jsf/) is not available."

If I try to use "/test" as pattern, then it works for www.example.com/test.

The following files are present in web-root:

```
index.xhtml
index.html
```

The index.html contains the redirect

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=index.jsf">
```

Thank you very much.

PS: PrettyFaces 3.3.2, JSF 2, PrimeFaces 3.1.1

EDIT:
I got it work!
I needed to delete the browser cache. I don't know why... but it helped. Thank you for your answers anyway!

Comment: Have you tried just using index instead of index.jsf since you have the redirect in the index.html file

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about the PrettyFaces part, but you can also just change the `FacesServlet` mapping from `*.jsf` to `*.xhtml` and then use `<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>` instead and get rid of that hacky `index.html`. This way you don't need to fiddle with virtual URLs and you also profit from the container's builtin welcome file facility.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers frequently cache 301 redirects so that they do not need to contact the old address in the future. Clearing your browser cache is the only way you can force your browser to contact the original URL again.